# Getting column names with sqsh -m bcp option enabled?

Tags: sql, sybase, sqsh

When I'm using sqsh in interactive mode, sometimes I like to run my query in the following way so I can get it in a nice csv file:

> 1> select * from Table where
>   Blah=Blah
>
> 2> go -m bcp >
>   /file/name/here

The only problem I have is that using the "-m bcp" option does not give me the column names in the output. Any idea how to get those column names in a "clean" way?

Answer (score 3):

There is a CSV display mode in sqsh have you tried that

Comment: Isn't `-m bcp` the csv mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
1> select * from Table where Blah=Blah
2> go -m csv > /file/name/here
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `csv` style mentioned in other answers, the default `horiz` style combined with an appropriate value in `colsep` (not `bcp_colsep`) will produce separated-output with column names.

```
1> \set colsep="|"

1> select * from Table where Blah=Blah
2> go
|heading1|heading2|
|--------|--------|
|row1    |col2    |
|row2    |col2    |
```

However, column values are padded and both the heading-underline and an initial column-separator before the first column are also printed. These could be stripped-off with `awk`, for example. Perhaps there is no panacea...

A tab character as column separator must be inserted literally with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> unless a recent `sqsh` is being used (information from this question: [What options are there for the sqsh style "csv" (or anyway to get tab-delimited out)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17314269/1184892)).